# Consulta LINQ Dataset en Datagridview filas repetidas

Tags: vb.net, linq

**1.** Tengo una consulta en LINQ (VB.NET):

```
Dim Consulta = From ConsultaEmisor In Emisor
               From ConsultaReceptor In Receptor
               From ConsultaComprobante In Comprobante
               Select New With {Mis campos}
```

**2.** Lleno un grid con la consulta:

```
Datagridview1.datasource = Consulta.toList
```

**3**.La consulta esta dentro de un FOR porque lleno mi dataset por medio de xmls: (En este caso solo 2)

```
For cont As Integer = 0 To lista - 1
   Dim PathFile As String = ("D:\XML SAT\" & ListBox1.SelectedItem & "\" & ListBox2.Items(cont))
   ds.ReadXml(PathFile)
```

**4**. Cuando se muestran los datos en el grid en la primera vuelta
se agrega una fila (Toma los datos de mi dataset por medio de la consulta LINQ para unir los nodos (datable) del XML), todo bien hasta ahí, pero en la segunda vuelta los duplica por la cantidad de "from" que tengo en mi Consulta , que en este caso son 3 From (Emisor,Receptor y Comprobante)

**5**.No puedo usar un join ya que ninguna tabla tiene un campo que pueda relacionar como llave principal.

**6**.Alguien conoce una manera que no sea el metodo merge para  juntar mis datatable en el grid?

La forma tradicional es

```
Datagridview1.datasource = dataset.tables("Tabla1")
Datagridview1.datasource = dataset.tables("Tabla2")
Datagridview1.datasource = dataset.tables("Tabla3")
```

Pero el Grid solo llenara sus columnas con la ultima tabla que se le asigne al source...

Ya llevo mucho tiempo en esto alguien podria ayudarme?

Saludos!

Comment: sino puedes usar el Merge() del datatable y tampoco el join o union de linq entonces no conozco ningun alternativa para solucionar el problema que planteas

Comment: Coincido con Leandro, porque razón no usar merge()?

Comment: Tengo 3 tablas, las primeras 2 ambas tienen como campos rfc y nombre
entonces con el merge en vez de ponerme 4 columnas me pone 2 y agrega los datos de ambas en una y no en su columna correspondientes y sobre mi tercera tabla esa queda en el grid en sus campos correspondientes pero en vez de que salga a lado en las filas salta espacio y quedan los datos desfasados

Comment: Solo quiero las 3 tablas (nodos) que tiene un xml en un grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo logre con un join usando LINQ

resulta que el xml tenia un campo en común en cada uno de sus nodos llamado

"comprobante_Id"

desconocia la existencia de este campo porque al abrir el xml este no es visible y no entiendo porque

di con él por equivocación.. tratando de implementar un codigo se mando un mensaje que me decia que
ya habia un campo llamado comprobante_Id  hice un select con LINQ a cada una de las 3 tablas trayendo el campo y resultaba que si existia despues hice el join correspondiente para uni todo, fue muy estresante tratar de hacer algo que como comenta Leandro no es posible almenos sin utilizar alguno de esos metodos, lo que me podrian explicar es como ver todos los campos escondidos que tiene un xml , creo que hay algo de el esquema .. pero desconozco como se maneje eso

Saludos!